# Fibonacci sequence convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am having trouble expressing the radius $\rho$ with respect to $ z_1 $ and $ z_2 $, and therefore $\alpha$ and $\beta$. 
Let    $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $a_n$$zⁿ$ be an integer series whose coefficients are defined by the following recurrence relations: $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$ and, for $n ≥ 2$,
$$a_n = αa_{n − 1} + βa_{n − 2}$$ where $α$, $β$ $∈$ $\mathbb{C}$ are different from zero.
Someone can give me hints to do this?

Comment: What are $z_1$ and $z_2$?

Comment: Numbers in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n = \alpha a_{n − 1} + \beta a_{n − 2}$$
Solve
$$\lambda^2=\alpha\lambda+\beta$$
$$\lambda_1=\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }}{2} ;\;\lambda_2=\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }}{2} $$
Solution is $$a_n=p\lambda_1^n+q\lambda_2^n$$
as $a_0=1$ we know that $p+q=1$ and as $a_1=2$ we have $p\lambda_1+q\lambda_2=2$

$$p= \frac{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }+\alpha -4}{2 \sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }},q= \frac{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }-\alpha +4}{2 \sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }}$$

Finally we have, thanks to *Mathematica*
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\frac{4 (\alpha  z-2 z-1)}{\left(z \sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }-\alpha  z+2\right) \left(z \sqrt{\alpha ^2+4 \beta }+\alpha  z-2\right)}$$